# Convert all the Unix Timestamp strings on a Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, unix-timestamp

I'm using a Wordpress plugin named EventOn to create events on a website. The plugin creates a custom post for each event and will store the event date in a meta key called **evcal_srow**
where the value is stored in Unix time (eg 1464739500).

Now what I'm trying to achieve here is to pull these custom posts via Slider Revolution by using a shortcode provided by the slider to pull a custom field from the custom post, in this particular case the shortcode is **{{meta:evcal_srow}}**

Here is how I'm generating the thumbnails via slider revo's navigation editor:

```
<span class="tp-thumb-image">

        <h3 class="thumb-event-title">
          {{title}}
        </h3>

        <h2 class="thumb-event-date" style="color:#fff">
          {{meta:evcal_srow}}
        </h2>

</span>
```

Everything works fine as I'm able to pull post title, featured image and date successfully, but I'd need to convert the date to a human format.

If I was creating a normal page then I'd create a template file and add something like

```
<?php
    $ts = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'evcal_srow', true);
    $date = new DateTime("@$ts");
    echo "<div class='datum'>".$date->format('d.m.Y')."</div><div class='uhrzeit'>".$date->format('H:i')."</div>";
?>
```

though the way I'm pulling data is via the slider settings so there is no way I can use php in this scenario because it's not allowed (unless you have a better idea of course!). Also I can't edit the plugin files directly as I need to be able to update it in future and I'm not sure there is anything similar to a child theme for the plugins.

The first thing I'd think about is to convert all the selectors **.thumb-event-date** in the page after the page loads, maybe using some JS or jQuery, I've tried many ways but can't get any positive results.

It would be super great if anybody would be able to come up with a solution.
Thank you very much for your time indeed.

## Solution *(thanks a lot Paul!)*

- Go to your slider settings
- Find the **Custom Javascript** section and
  paste this into it:

  ```
  revapi1.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() { // Replace the number 1 in revapi1.on with the ID of your slider

      jQuery('.thumb-event-date').each(function(index, value) { // Replace .thumb-event-date with the selector that contains the unix time string
          jQuery(value).html(new Date(jQuery(value).html()*1000).toISOString()); 
      });
  ```

  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.thumb-event-date').each(function(index, value) {
  $(value).html(new Date($(value).html()*1000).toISOString()); // put whatever Date() method you want/need (to show human readable format) 
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help Paulooze your snippet does make sense though it won't work :/ Here is the  code I'm using now: `<script>jQuery('.thumb-event-date').each(function(index, value) {
  jQuery(value).html(new Date(jQuery(value).html()*1000).toISOString());
});</script>` No idea why :( tried to put this script between the head tags and also tried in the body.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why wont it work? I tried it by myself (I put your timestamps in ul and ran this code and it converted the values to ISO Strings).

Comment: it just doesnt convert the string. The console doesnt display any errors neither.

Comment: Ok, just try `console.log($(value).html());` inside the `each` loop and let me know what it shows in console.

Comment: I put this before </body>   `<script>

  jQuery('.thumb-event-date').each(function(index, value) {
    console.log(jQuery(value).html());
  });

  </script> ` and the console is just blank. I've also tried to put it between the <head> tags and after <body> but still no luck..

Comment: put the whole code inside `$(document).ready(function() {//...this code here});`

Comment: Great! That didnt work straight away but you gave me an idea so I checked the slider revolution API doc and put this script in the plugin's custom JS tab (in the slider settings) ` revapi1.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {
        
            jQuery('.thumb-event-date').each(function(index, value) {
                jQuery(value).html(new Date(jQuery(value).html()*1000).toISOString()); 
                //console.log(jQuery(value).html());
            }); 
        
    }); ` and it does work! Only issue is it doesnt show the day but I guess I'll have to play with Date() a bit?